# spring boot jdbc config with vault backend

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-vault-config

I am using spring boot and spring vault cloud : it works very well when i am loading a specific key in not code like :

```
@Value("${login}")
String login;
```

The value is correctly read from the secrets i specified under my secret backend configuration.

However, i can't figure out how to handle spring automatic properties.
Let's say i want to create a spring jdbc database connection :

```
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder
            .create()
            .build();
}
```

As you can see, i don"t define driverClassName, user, password, url..
If i define spring.jdbc.* in the application.yml, it works

But my need is to read those properties from a hashicorp vault secret.

=> How i can in a general approach define the various spring boot values into vault secrets ?

Guillaume

Answer (score 0):

OK i can answer to my own question :

when creating a default Datasource, spring looks for spring.datasource.* keys in its propertySource, in the yml file and in the vault for my specific case.

Defining a secret having key in properties format, like spring.datasource.password, totally works when initializing the DS bean

Hope it helps someone!

Guillaume